# Updating a dictionary in a JSON File

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Trying to update a certain dictionary in a json file but unable to do so as it just adds a new dictionary to the database rather than being under the dictionary.
An example, of what I'm trying to achieve is:

Before running the function the database looks like:

```
{
    "account_details": [
        {
            "Username": "TestingUsername",
            "Password": "232Pass",
            "Email": "TestingEmail@outlook.com",
            "Token": "18973871HIA"
        }
    ]
}
```

After running the function this is what the database looks like:

```
{
    "account_details": [
        {
            "Username": "TestingUsername",
            "Password": "232Pass",
            "Email": "TestingEmail@outlook.com",
            "Token": "18973871HIA"
        }
    ]
}{
    "Username": "TestingUsername",
    "Password": "232Pass",
    "Email": "TestingEmail@outlook.com",
    "Token": "18973871HIA",
    "Details": {
        "Preset1": {
            "Username": "TestingUsername",
            "Password": "TestingPassword3",
            "URL": "TestingURL.com:"
        }
    }
}
```

The functions, function is to take in the Presetname (TestingPreset39), under the Details dictionary, which then includes the Username (Testing_username) , Password (TestingPresetPassword) & Url (preset.com).

However, what I want it to look like is:

```
{
    "account_details": [
        {
            "Username": "ComputingCourse32",
            "Password": "NoNUmbers",
            "Email": "computingcw@cwl.com",
            "Token": "4L8PWWRFYL",
            "Testing": "Testing",
            "Details": {
                "Preset1": {
                    "Username": "Username1",
                    "Password": "Password1",
                    "URL": "http://testing.cwl.com"
                }
            }
        },
```

I've tried to convert the database into a list as a way to append to the list then putting it in the database:

```
   with open("testaccount.json", "r+") as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        for record in data["account_details"]:
            if record["Username"] == username:
                if type(record) is dict:
                    data = [record]
                    # data['specific_dict'].append(new_dict)

                    data.append ({
                        "Details" : {
                        "Preset1":{
                        "Username": "TestingUsername",
                        "Password": "TestingPassword",
                        "URL": "TestingURL.com"
                        }
                        }
                    })
                   
                    print(data)
```

Also, I've tried to use the update() function:

```
with open("testaccount.json", "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    for record in data["account_details"]:
        if record["Username"] == "TestingUsername":
            new_data = {"Details":{
                "Preset1":{
                "Username": "TestingUsername",
                "Password": "TestingPassword3",
                "URL": "TestingURL.com:"
                }
            }}
            record.update(new_data)
            print(record)
```

Though both ways put the new data in the database neither ways actually add it under the dictionary.

[image]

Comment: Why does the `after` image look exactly like the `before` image? Why are you posting images of text when you could have cut and pasted the text itself into your question?

Comment: When opening with `r+` your pointer is at the beginning. `json.load` moves it to the end, so `json.dump` appends to the file. Properly update the records in `data` and overwrite the file.

Comment: @ivvija Wouldn't this overwrite everything in the database? 
I like the idea of overwriting but I would only want to overwrite a specific dictionary any idea on how this would be done?

Comment: With `json` format data in a file, you cannot reliably overwrite parts of the file. You should read the entire file, make changes as python objects, and finally write the entire file back.

Answer (score 1):

> *With `json` format data in a file, you cannot reliably overwrite parts of the file. You should read the entire file, make changes as python objects, and finally write the entire file back.* – [quamrana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4834/quamrana)

You can do so with the code below.<sup>([view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xpMC.png))</sup>

```py
with open('testaccount.json', 'r') as f: 
    data = json.load(f)

for ri, record in enumerate(data["account_details"]):
    if record["Username"] == "TestingUsername":
        new_data = {'Details': {'Preset1': {
                    'Username': 'TestingUsername',
                    'Password': 'TestingPassword3',
                    'URL': 'TestingURL.com:'          }}}
        
        data["account_details"][ri].update(new_data)
# print(data)

with open('testaccount.json', 'w') as f: 
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

<sup>**Note that *`record.update(new_data)`* would not affect `data` as `record` is just a copy of `data["account_details"][ri]`.**</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to add accounts rather than overwriting?
This works as intended but I wanna be able to add more presets.

Comment: @Trqzy No. As stated, JSON files can't added to or updated if you want to maintain valid json structures - you'll always have to load, edit and overwrite like this. If you want to be able to append, you'll need to store your data as CSV or something, and if you want to be able to interact [i.e., edit previous data as well without loading] you could try something like .db files with [SQLite](https://towardsdatascience.com/d553989c87bd), but both will require you to flatten your data, so you'll have at least 2 tables if you don't want data redundancies

Comment: @Trqzy If you don't want to flatten, I think there's also NoSQL options like mogodb support nested structures, but I'm not so familiar with that, and I don't know if the data can be interactable from a file like with SQLite

Comment: Thing is I have to use a JSON file. But taking in the solution you gave, can't I just add more presets then overwrite that record? If I was to put the Details dictionary into a list and then add to it then overwrite the dictionary would this not work?

Comment: @Trqzy yes ofc you can add/edit as much as you like before overwriting. You can do whatever you like before `.dump`

Comment: What would the code be like if I wanted to add to the details dictionary then overwrite it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252103/discussion-between-trqzy-and-driftr95).